# SFINAE a templated function for shared_ptrs vs normal ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, sfinae

please see the following short snippet:

```
template<typename M, typename V>
void MapToVector(const M &map, V &vec) {
    for (const auto &mapElem : map) {
        vec.push_back(mapElem.second.get());
    }
}
```

In the code above I am converting a std::map for shared_ptrs to some object and inserting them into a vector of raw pointers to the same type.

My goal is to SFINAE this function so that it would pick either the function above or the following function.

```
template<typename M, typename V>
void MapToVector(const M &map, V &vec) {
    for (const auto &mapElem : map) {
        vec.push_back(mapElem.second);
    }
}
```

I have only read through enable_if and another article about member detection:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector

However the 2 articles can't be mixed since the Member detector examples given instantiates real objects which cannot be used as template arguments (or perhaps it could but I have no idea how to).

See my following attempt at using the enable_if and member detector together:

```
template<typename M, typename V,
    typename std::enable_if<typename HasMember_get<typename V::value_type>::value>::type
    >
void MapToVector(const M &map, V &vec) {
    for (const auto &mapElem : map) {
        vec.push_back(mapElem.second.get());
    }
}

template<typename M, typename V>
void MapToVector(const M &map, V &vec) {
    for (const auto &mapElem : map) {
        vec.push_back(mapElem.second);
    }
}
```

Note that in my SFINAE attempt I have another problem of deducing the type stored within the vector:

```
template<typename M, typename V,
    typename std::enable_if<typename HasMember_get<typename V::value_type>::value>::type
    >
```

I'm think that there's also a problem of non-deduced context for V::value_type but I'm still not certain if that's actually the problem.
With the above snippet the compile error is: Error  3   error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::enable_if'

Any help in identifying the current issues will be greatly appreciated.
If there is a cleaner and more suitable approach, an example to such an approach would also be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: Not sure, but I would lean toward using SFINAE via decltype on get()--that's the first thing I would try.

Comment: If you're converting shared to weak pointers, you should be using the [`weak_ptr(const shared_ptr&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr) ctor anyway, instead of using the raw pointer from `get()`, which makes the whole question moot.

Comment: My bad, I used the term weak_ptr collaterally with raw pointers. I will edit that in my post.

Comment: Overload based on value_type equality to shared_ptr (by detecting this type as part of M)

Comment: How about just defining two overloads of `make_raw`, one taking a shared pointer and returning the result of `.get()`, one taking a raw pointer and returning the argument, and calling that from a single function template `MapToVector()`? Also, consider `std::transform` :)

Comment: @AndyProwl your overload idea coupled with transform seems like a really good simplification of the problem. I will try that with my project and see how that goes. However I would still like a solution to my SFINAE approach so that I can see where I went wrong.

Comment: Seems you forgotten a `=` between `typename` and `std::enable_if`. Or rather it should be `typename = typename std::enable_if...`

Comment: You can simply use `&*`.. I would prefer that.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb could you elaborate on that? Not sure what do you mean.